# Why can I delete an edge from a graph?

Tags: graph-theory

The two problems below are solved by removing the edge `e` and reasoning about the degrees of the new graphs. Why can I arbitrarily remove edges and still prove facts on the previous graph? I can't convince myself particularly on the second problem why this idea works.

Problem 1:

A graph G is made of two subgraphs, A and B with |A|=|B|. A and B "share" one edge `e = (a, b)`, `a` in A and `b` in B. G is regular of degree 3. Prove that |A| is odd.

Problem 2:

A graph G is made of four subgraphs, A, B, C, D. G is regular of degree 4 and A, B, C, D share one vertex `v`; there is an edge `e = (v, a)`, one `(v, b)`, one `(v, c)` and one `(v, d)`. Prove that G does not exist. [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RjGl8.jpg).

> Remove `e`: A is of degree 4 but for one vertex of degree 3. By the theorem for which odd degree vertices are even, A can't exist, and so can't G.

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: @AnotherUser welcome to Mathematics SE. I'm not looking for an answer; the answer is there in my post. What I'm looking for is (as posted): why does the technique work? Why can I remove an edge and reason about that new graph "on behalf of" the old graph? My question is different to what you say

Comment: Not sure where your confusion lies.  Well, possibly it is in the abuse of notation.  I would not have used $A$ to denote both the subgraph of $G$ *and* the same subgraph with one vertex and one edge deleted.  It's always a bad idea to use one variable to denote more than one thing.  I'd have said something like, "let $A_1$ denote the subgraph $A$ with vertex $v$ and edge $(a,v)$ deleted.  Then $A_1$ is a graph with exactly one odd vertex, and no such graph can exist."

Comment: @lulu my confusion lies on the fact that from $A_1$ we draw conclusions about $A$, the original one. Those are two different graphs; why can we reason about the original one from the new one without an edge? How's that possible?

Comment: If $G$ exists, then so does the graph $G'$ obtained by deleting edge $e$? But if $G'$ cannot exist and we are able to create $G'$ from $G$, by extension, $G$ should not exist, right?

Comment: Assuming the graph $A$ existed, I produced a (closely related) graph $A_1$ which obviously can't exist.  Therefore $A$ could not exist.

Comment: Are the vertices of $A,B,C,D$ disjoint? Are there edges between vertices of $A,B$ in the graph $G$?

Comment: @UmeshShankar edited